# Timer shows wrong results

Tags: javascript

```
var seconds_lapsed = 0;

function tick() {    
    seconds_lapsed++;
}

function countup() { 
    setTimeout(function () {
        if (stopped) return; // stop the loop
        if (!is_paused()) {
            tick();
            show_time_left();            
        }
        countup(); // <--- this is the "loop"
    }, 1000);
}
```

This is the core of my timer. Of course I have some view to represent the result. But ticking is done here.

**The problem**

It shows wrong time. Have a look at this:

[image]

The timer was set for 3 hours. Twelve minutes lapsed. And the discrepancy is almost 1.5 minutes.

In the other window the timer by Google is working. This one:

[image]

So, I just compared my timer with that of google. I started them almost at once. The difference should be no more than a couple of seconds (to switch the window and press the button).

What is the reason for this, and how can I correct it?

Comment: Timeouts are not precise, use Date object to get the time instead of counting elapsed seconds.

Answer (score 2):

setTimeout with an interval of 1000 does NOT run exactly after every 1 seconds.
It schedules to run after 1 second, but can be delayed with by actions running at that time.

A better way of solving this is by calculating via date difference.
I took your sample (added the missing vars/funcs) and changed the tick() function to use date diffs.

```
var seconds_lapsed = 0;
var startDateTime = new Date();
var stopped = false;
var is_paused = function() { return false; }

function tick() {    
    datediffInms =  new Date() - startDateTime;
    seconds_lapsed = Math.round(datediffInms / 1000);
}

function countup() { 
    setTimeout(function () {
        if (stopped) return; // stop the loop
        if (!is_paused()) {
            tick();
            //show_time_left();            
            console.log(seconds_lapsed)
        }
        countup(); // <--- this is the "loop"
    }, 1000);
}


countup();
```

Comment: Thank you. But your solution doesn't seem to show correct time.  If I have not distorted it of course. 

http://www.fotolink.su/v.php?id=10261e06e3df0c36d3be9ccd90d2f8db

My code: https://dpaste.org/f622

Comment: I am going to need more information. Logically, there should be no difference. We keep the start datetime in a variable and always calc the difference with that starting point. Even if the timeout would fire at irregular intervals, this kind of offset should not happen. Your code sample does not show everything as ```is_paused()```, ```stopped``` and ```startDateTime``` are not included. I suspect something is happening there i am not aware off.